# How can I uninstall a package that was installed by Nuxeo Studio?

Tags: nuxeo

I used Nuxeo Studio for research purposes and created a Schema and added it to my local server using the Nuxeo Chrome Extension is hot deploy.

Now, what if I need to uninstall the package?

I tried to use the `./nuxeoctl mp-uninstall <package-name-installer-by-studio>` to achieve that. Apparently, it worked. **However, my local server fails to start again and, when the hot reload is called again, it hangs up saying:**

```
data/myWorkflow.zip not found in <path>/nuxeo-server-10.10-tomcat/nxserver/bundles/<package>.jar
```

also:

```
org.nuxeo.ecm.webengine.app.WebEngineExceptionMapper] org.nuxeo.ecm.core.api.NuxeoException: Failed to invoke operation: Service.HotReloadStudioSnapshot
```

I am led to think that this is badly done/programmed: there should be an error proof way to uninstall the packages installed by Studio, since Studio won't be the only tool to be used in a big project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to install/uninstall the package with another strategy: I didn't hot reload it with Nuxeo Chrome Extension. I just downloaded the package and installed it using Nuxeo-CLI. Then, I was able to uninstall it without any issues.

I noticed that this gives me more control since I can keep the package that was generated, I can inspect what changes were made (and understand what happened in a more open way), and then install/uninstall it manually.

Since I didn't figure out the problem that is with Nuxeo Chrome Extension, I chose not to use it for a while.